# Reputation Fluctuating?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I joined this morning and I rounded up around 11 RP. Suddenly, it fell to a 7 then to a 3, then strangely back up to a 7.

Is there something I'm missing out here? Some clarity would be much appeciated.

Comment: [Your reputation tab](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/120144/wulfinite?tab=reputation) is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your user profile can be very helpful, as Frank points out. However, if you are simply trying to assess reputation, you have a button available to you across all Stack Exchange sites, including Arqade.

[image]

Pressing on this button gives you a drop down of all reputation gain/loss within a set period. Seperated into the last day, the last week, and the last month, this drop down will give you a reference of any change to your reputation within the last month. Assuming you are a regular Arqadian, this can be a quick and easy way to keep up to date with an reputation changes. You should also note that this will show you rep changes across **all stack exchange sites**, as you can see by my +100 to Mathematics for "being trusted".

I feel it important to note that while Frank has taken you "the long way", albeit a rather insignificant difference, he has pointed out a much more powerful analysis tool; From the user profile, you can view other elements, including your questions and answers. Each listing also gives you a good overview of the overall rating, which in turn gives you an idea on what is attracting up votes and down votes.

Comment: Note that if you link to `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation`, then anyone who visits the link will be taken to [their personal reputation tab, like so](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). This makes it useful to link to the various parts of a profile page without restricting it to a single user's page :)

Answer (score 6):

You recieved an upvote, which awards +10 reputation.

Then, you received several downvotes, each of which costs you -2 reputation.

The resultant net change leaves you at your current rep.

Comment: Ah right, thank you very much.